# Suggestions for saving cron based scheduled data

Tags: php, mysql

I have an algorithm which requires scheduled task that runs a script on a regular basis (every minute). I want to store this data and access those values ranging from last hour to last 24 hrs.

I've looked into saving an array of data to a single mysql field. I know serialize() and unserialize() functions will do.

Can you suggest any other way to store those cron scheduled task values or will array be sufficient?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what type of data you are storing? It's nearly impossible to recommend the proper solutions when we don't know what you're storing.

Comment: @brad Those are numerical values that are needed to be stored

Comment: Can you please provide an **example** of the data? Simply saying 'numbers' does not help.

Comment: Do you have some problem with connecting to the database and using `insert` ?  Each time slice should have a separate row in whatever table you are using to store the data.

Comment: Also, I wonder if we are able to properly answer your question, because we don't know you will use the data later on. Serialising the data in a single fields makes it harder to process the data later on; at least if you need to 'query' the content via SQL

Comment: Want to take number of shares of a link from twitter using a function

Comment: function readTwitterShares($url) {
 $s = file_get_contents("http://urls.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json".
   "?callback=?&url=".urlencode($url));
   preg_match("#(\"count\"):([0-9]*)#",$s,$ar);
   return isset($ar[2]) ? $ar[2] : 0;
}
 
echo readTwitterShares("http://abc123.com");

Comment: @GordonLinoff considering that thing each link would have around 60 rows for an hour passed

Comment: @prateek . . . Are you trying to make a point?  Databases are designed for such a data load.  That is only 525,600 rows in a year.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, is there not a way I can save all data in a single row and that can be accessible by queries easily?? or can you tell me any other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is simply to insert the data into a table in MySQL.  The table should look something like this:

```
create table MinuteStats as (
    MinuteStatsId int not null auto_increment,
    TimeOfMeasurement datetime,
    Measure1 int,
    Measure2 int,
    CreatedAt TimeStamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Then, every minute, do something like:

```
insert into MinuteStats(TimeOfMeasurement, Measure1, Measure1)
    select <time>, <measure1>, <measure2>
```

You will then have the data in a nice format for subsequent processing.

Comment: Thanks, I had this in mind. One thing to ask that measure1 , measure2 , ..... measureN etc are those columns which will store values every minute and keep on increasing with time?

Comment: @prateek . . . No, those are the values that you want to store each minute.  Perhaps you only have one value.  In that case, there would be only one column.

Comment: Gordon, MySQL 5.0 Column-Count Limits 4096 columns per table. On doing  some math, 24hrs x 60mins = 1440 columns plus extras for other purposes.
It gives error ---> too many columns in the table <-----, how to cope up with this?

Comment: @prateek . . . Each minute would be in a separate *row* not a separate *column*.

Answer (score 0):

memcache can store for a particualer time. Seeing its basically an array it should do fine.

Set the timeout to (60*60*24=) 86400